# Why won't a firmware update install on my newly upgraded to 21.04 Thinkpad laptop?

Tags: updates, thinkpad, firmware, fwupd

The 'Ubuntu Software' application tells me me I have a firmware update available (screenshot below). I have installed many of those on this laptop without problems but this time when I click "Install" the update notification disappears and then shows up again as if I haven't done anything. I can keep clicking 'Install' but it keeps coming back after a couple of seconds. I then thought I would reboot and maybe the update would install before boot as it has in the past. Nothing, just a normal boot, but I notice a lockup/pause for a couple of seconds during shutdown I haven't noticed before.

I also tried using fwupd but got lost since there's one snap version and one deb version available. The snap version won't run and give me a cryptic error while the deb version has the same problem as 'Ubuntu Software'. It tells me I have an update, I choose to install it and it's being downloaded. Now I am getting a reboot y/n option I do not get from 'Ubuntu Software' and I choose reboot y. I reboot. Same thing, nothing other than the pause during shutdown. I boot normally again and still have the same update available right after I log in to my user account.

How can I fix this and get the firmware update installed? Annoying to get the update available over and over and not be able to install it. This is the update in question:

[image: Thinkpad Firmware update]

Comment: I have the exact same problem with the 6th gen. Seems to be a general problem with Lenovo + Ubuntu.

Comment: Same here with a T14s, fwupd also does not work correctly (just as you describe).